# Obfuscate code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way of Obfuscating code in Eclipse when the file is built, rather than using external software? Is there a plugin that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google gives me at least 2 interesting matches

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=145868&

http://code.google.com/p/obfuscate4e/

Comment: Thanks :D I used the second one and it looks great!